# Ant call a target with N parameters

Tags: javascript, ant, parameters, target

I'd like to call a target with multiple parameters and be able to loop through those, without knowing what their name or number are. (w/ javascript or whatever)

Lets say I call a target like this,

```
<antcall target="dummy">
   <param name="p1" value="v1"/>
   <param name="p2" value="v2"/>
   .
   .
   .
   <param name="pn" value="vn"/>
</antcall>
```

At this point I know how many parameters there are, but it'll change from a call to another, and somehow I'd like to do that

```
<target name="dummy">

   <script language="javascript">
     var params = self.getOwningTarget().getParameters(); // retrieve the params list
     params.forEach(function(param) {
        var echo = project.createTask("echo");
        echo.setMessage(param);
        echo.perform();
     });
   </script>

</target>
```

It doesn't have to be javascript ofc, if you have any idea I'd appreciate it, if it is possible at all !

Answer (score 0):

not sure about ant but in javascript you would iterate over array items like that

```
params.forEach(function(item) {
    echo(item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I failed that one, but looping through them isn't the problem here, what I'd mostly like to know is how to retrieve the parameters, one way or another.

(Gonna edit that error though :') )